# Conditional call to base constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Currently, I have a based class with two different constructors:

```
class Base {
public:
   Base(std::string filname){...}
   Base(int a, int b) {...}
};
```

and a derived class of Base class. What I would like to do is to choose which constructor call inside the constructor of the derived class, but not in the initializer list. Something like this:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        if( /* exists("myFile") */ )
            this->Base("myFile");
        else
            this->Base(1,2);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that?, or because the base class is initialize before the derived class, the only way to call to the base constructor is in the initializer list?

Thanks

Comment: Which base constructor will be called is determined at compile time. There's no way around that. Maybe you can get what you want but constructing a `Base` locally and move-constructing the actual base. Otherwise, you might want to put that logic into your `Base` constructor.

Comment: Can you modify the code of `Base` class?

Comment: As an aside, `if file_exists open_file` is a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The choice of which base constructor is called happens before the body of the function and there's no way to change it at run time like that. However, you might be able to get close. If the base class also has a move constructor, or you could you add one, you could use that:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived()
        : Base{ exists("myFile") ? Base{"myFile"} : Base{1, 2} } {
    }
}
```

This will call `exists("myFile")`; if that returns `true`, it will construct a temporary `Base` using the first constructor, and if it returns `false` it will construct a temporary `Base` using the second constructor. Either way, it will then construct the *actual* base subobject using this temporary.

Comment: Again, there is no conditional invocation of base class constructor here. It is always unconditionally constructed using copy constructor / move constructor / causes compilation error depending on base class implementation.

Comment: @VTT There's no conditional invocation of the copy/move constructor. There is conditional invocation of the string/two ints constructor, which is what's desired. Since C++17 there is actually *no* invocation of the copy/move constructor and it is as though it chose which constructor to use for the base subobject directly.

Comment: "Since C++17" is an important qualifier! That aside this is the best answer

Comment: This only works if Base{"myFile"} is instantiable. If the Base class is an abstract base class, it does not work. Any alternatives in this case?

Comment: @MartinHierholzer The other answer, about factory functions, should still work, but I don’t think there’s a way to do it just in a constructor without having to modify `Base`.

Comment: Wait, no, I was wrong.  You can use private delegating constructors (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor) and the ternary operator, similar to how the base constructor is used here.  That might recuire some code duplication in the constructors, though.

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for the hint, I will try that!

Comment: Yes this works, see my new answer below. Of course it's more lengthy, so it only makes sense if the Base class is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate that by introducing a factory function:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(std::string filname);
    Base(int a, int b);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived(std::string filname) : Base(filname) {}
    Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a, b) {}
public:
    static Derived create() {
        if( /* exists("myFile") */ )
            return Derived("myFile");
        else
            return Derived(1,2);
    }
};

int main(){
    auto d = Derived::create();
}
```

---

Alternatively, if derivation from `Base` is not required, an instance of `Base` can be held as a member (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::aligned_storage`) that you can initialise however you please.

Comment: Though these are valid workarounds there is no conditional invocation of base class constructor here. It is always unconditionally constructed using copy constructor / move constructor / causes compilation error depending on base class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DanielH comment in his answer I have developed an alternative solution which also works with abstract base classes in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Base {

    Base(int x) {
      std::cout << "Base x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
    
    Base() {
      std::cout << "Base default" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void foo() = 0;

};


struct Derived : Base {

    struct TagA {};
    struct TagB {};

    Derived(bool condition)
    : Derived(condition ? Derived{TagA()} : Derived{TagB()})
    {}
    
    void foo() override {}
    
  private:
  
    Derived(TagA dummy)
    : Base(42)
    {
      std::cout << "Derived A dummy" << std::endl;
    }
    Derived(TagB dummy)
    {
      std::cout << "Derived B dummy" << std::endl;
    }



};


int main() {

    std::cout << "Construct Derived with false" << std::endl; 
    Derived x(false);

    std::cout << "Construct Derived with true" << std::endl; 
    Derived y(true);
  

}
```